# Creating a 3 Elasticsearch Cluster and 1 Balancer node with Kibana using dockerfile in same cluster environment

Tags: elasticsearch, dockerfile, cluster-computing

Creating a 3 Elasticsearch Cluster and 1 Balancer node with Kibana using dockerfile in same cluster environment

Could you please help me in creation of dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Navin recommend you to use docker-compose to set up the cluster with ease.
You can refer to the docker compose file

https://gist.github.com/ggsood/106400a679e7dc9dbe195d995d099e1b

It will create you a 3 Node ES cluster with 1 Master, 2 Data Nodes and 1 Kibana instance.

Please do share any feedback.

Comment: i was using this below docker file to run it but it throws many errors ..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/navin6m/d15ac0f78d383c5b3c565ecc048acffa

Comment: No problem I am glad it helped.

Comment: Hi Gaurav Do you have any dockerfile for setting up new rabbitmq on 3 clusters and new cluster on redis ..thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Navin did you check this repository for bringing up a Rabbitmq cluster https://github.com/pardahlman/docker-rabbitmq-cluster